# PHP - HTML - Preview Function

Tags: php, html

today I tried to make a PHP 'HTML'-Editor,
You can write your 'HTML'-Code, Preview it, and send it to my Email.
Here's the code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
//     $to = file_get_contents('to.txt');
$to = "jonas.geiler@gmail.com";
$subject = "Form to email message";
$message = $_POST["message"];
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: Skayos Blog <blog.skayo@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
} else if (isset($_POST['preview'])){
 $output = $_POST["message"];
 echo $output;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Form submission</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Message:<br>
        <textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30">&lt;html&gt; &lt;body&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;</textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem: If I press Preview, the side reloads with the preview, and the code gets deleted.
Is there a easy way to make the code stay in the textarea?

Thanks,
Skayo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1) Easy solution when is your code posted change value of textarea.

```
<?php    
    $msg = ""; 
    if (strlen($_POST['message'] > 0)
        $msg = $_POST['message'];
?>

Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" 
value="<?php echo $msg; ?>" cols="30">&lt;html&gt; 
&lt;body&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;</textarea><br>
```

## 2) You can load content dynamically with AJAX without reloading page.

```
<script>
function prewiev() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "preview.php?str=" + document.getElementById("message").value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


<form action="" method="post">
    Message:<br>
   <textarea id="message" rows="5" name="message" cols="30">
       &lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt; &lt;/body&gt; 
       &lt;/html&gt;
   </textarea><br>
   <button name="preview" onClick="prewiev()">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```